# Why are my input boxes showing undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The `name` and `email` input boxes are showing undefined when I click the submit button which calls the `showDetails()` function. This also happens when there are values in the inputboxes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDetails(){

    var e = document.getElementById("email");
    //var t = document.getElementById("t");
    var n = document.getElementById("name");
    var m = document.getElementById("m");

    var c;
    var r;
    document.getElementById("email").value = c;
    document.getElementById("name").value = r;
    document.getElementById("t").value = "Your name is: "+r+" and your email is: "+c;
}
</script>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: you're assigning the values of `email` and `name` to `c` and `r` respectively, neither have any value set (you've got them the wrong way round)

Comment: vars `c` and `r` are not defined, and you assigned them to the element values. EVERY time the function is called.

Comment: Yeah, this is totally backwards: `document.getElementById("email").value = c`. All you need here is `c = e.value`

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is because you're assigning the value to undefined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showDetails() {

    var e = document.getElementById("email");
    //var t = document.getElementById("t");
    var n = document.getElementById("name");
    var m = document.getElementById("m");

    var c = document.getElementById("email").value; // Here you set it the value = undefined variable
    var r = document.getElementById("name").value;

    document.getElementById("t").value = "Your name is: " + r + " and your email is: " + c;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: or `var c = e.value` and `var r = n.value`

Comment: @billyonecan Absolutely!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the assignment. Try this.

```
c=document.getElementById("email").value;r=document.getElementById("name").value;
```